# jq result iteration in bash

Tags: bash, jq

I have this jq output from a CLI command

```
["test-KEY","test-PASSWORD"]
```

Assigned that output to a bash variable in this manner

```
secret_list=`mycli | jq`
```

I want to iterate though that output in bash & perform another CLI command on each item.

So far I tried this block & is not coming desired command execution:

```
echo "secrets_list: "$secrets_list

length=${#secrets_list[@]}
echo "Number of secrets $length"

for secret in "${secrets_list[@]}"
do
      echo "$secret"
done
```

Output is

```
secrets_list: ["test-KEY","test-PASSWORD"]
Number of secrets 1
["test-KEY","test-PASSWORD"]
```

My expectation is to iterate through that array. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: "secret_list=`mycli | jq`" does not generate an array.

Comment: `$secrets_list` is not a bash array, it's a string. So `$(#secrets_list[@]}` is not the number of elements in the array.

Comment: BTW, you can also do `readarray -t secrets_list < <(mycli | jq -r '.[]')` to make `secrets_list` real/proper array.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Bash arrays are not JSON arrays and JSON arrays are not bash arrays. If you none of your values contains new lines, you could use `read` in a loop:

```
mycli | jq -r '.[]' | while read -r secret; do
  echo "$secret"
done
```